# Updating the screen resolution in centos7 in Hyper-V

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos, hyper-v, centos-7

I am unable to update my display resolution of Centos7 which was installed in the Hyper-v of Windows 8.1.

Earlier I have faced the same problem in VirtualBox but it was resolved after installing VirtualBox Guest Additions.

In hyper-v, after installing the Linux integration tools I can't use the mouse it and some other problem also happened. Can you give me any idea to get rid of this.  I have tried to use the following commands

```
grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:1280x1024"
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:1280x1024"
system-config-display --reconfig --set-resolution=1920x1200
```

but nothing helped me.

Comment: I tried the same commands many times and reboot each time. I can confirm grub is correctly configured with right argument by typing 'E' at startup and checking manually the startup script. But the size of the screen remains stuck to 1024x768

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a known problem with VMs on Hyper-V unable to set the screen to a high
resolution, with no way of changing it either from KDE System Settings or Hyper-V virtual machine properties.

The problem is with the frame buffer driver of Hyper-V.
CentOS provides a tool called `grubby` for managing `grub.cfg`
which is much easier to work with than editing `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub`.

To set the desired screen resolution under Hyper-V, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:2560x1440"
```

then reboot.
Replace `2560x1440` with the desired screen resolution.

If you find that you are still unable under Hyper-V to reach the desired
resolution, the other solution is to install [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/)
and use remote desktop.
See the article
[Install xrdp on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-xrdp-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html).

Comment: I finally reinstalled the system in a fresh VM, and re-applying the grubby command. I noticed that it worked only for a few screen resolution, but it worked. I still don't know why this was not possible in my previous VM, but anyway I can now work with this system. Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the [Hyper-V Linux Integration Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51612) as [explained here](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/installing-and-activating-hyper-v-linux-integration-services.html)?

Comment: Actually, I tried to change the display resolution of a VM under Fedora. I read in many places that the `video=hyperv_fb` is the right way to look, so I decided to re-open this question because the problem and the solution might be identical to RHL/CentOS. Unfortunately, Hyper-V Linux Integration doesn't support Fedora (I just tried)

Comment: Latest Fedora is supposed to natively support Hyper-V Linux Integration Services. Apparently theory doesn't match practice, or the integration is limited to only some screen resolutions.

Comment: After running grubby command, reset machine from Hyper-V. This helped me

Comment: I think that 2560x1440 resolution is not possible because the Hyper-V frame buffer is limited to something ridiculous like 8 MB. Can anyone verify this is still the case?

Comment: `su` doesn't work for me; I get error (su: unrecognized option '--update-kernel=ALL'). Using `sudo` instead worked.

Comment: @SaeedBaig: Thanks, it should have been `sudo` to start with. Fixed.

Comment: Seems there is a newer method (some of the above links broken) https://www.nakivo.com/blog/install-ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-with-enhanced-session/